# activity to fragment method calling in a thread with progressbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using this code, everything are working fine, but progressbar is not showing. I want to block my ui during the method implementation and want to show progressbar. I want to get behaviour like progressDialog.
Here is my method

```
public void effct(int effectNo) {
        final int finalEffectNO = effectNo;
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressLayoutLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageViewFragment.applyEffect(finalEffectNO);
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressLayoutLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

My xml code for progressLayout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressBarLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Loading"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, so what's your suggestion??

Comment: Your  method is executing really fast, so progress bar is actually doing its job fine. In low end devices, where the method might actually need some time to execute, your progress bar will show up

Comment: For such requirement I recommend you to use AlertDialog or custom Dialog.

Comment: @arifulislamarif, Do you want to make entire screen block from user interaction or just part of view?

Comment: yes i want to block full screen @ sameer Jani

Comment: Sorry @arifulislamarif, I could not get your point. For which answer you are telling yes? For entire screen or part of view?

Comment: I want to block full screen during the method implementation, it take 2-3 second to be implemented. It's showing everything except progressbar.

Comment: For above use you must use progressdialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread`, something like this :

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressLayoutLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void ... params ) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageViewFragment.applyEffect(finalEffectNO);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( final Void result ) {
            progressLayoutLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    }.execute();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it is showing progressbar. But app crashed after method implementation.

Comment: I also have tried in this way. When i try this, it stops to show progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a few ways to solve your problem - check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM) for more information. The most basic approach might be an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), which could look like this:

```
public class DummyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private final Window window;
  private final ProgressBar progressBar;

  public DummyAsyncTask(Window window, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.window = window;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
  }

  @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // Do the heavy lifting.
  }

  @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

You execute it by running `new DummyAsyncTask(/* params */).execute();`.

Do note that `AsyncTask` does **not** adhere to the lifecycle and holding a reference to a `Context` aware instance is just asking for trouble. A safer alternative might be using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata):

```
public void effect(int effectNo) {
  // Show progress and disable user interaction here.

  final ListData<Content> data = model.applyEffect(effectNo);
  data.observe(this, (Observer<Content>) c -> {
    // Apply results, hide progress & enable user interaction.
  });
}
```

Given the above, you should be careful how you handle showing & hiding progress, so you don’t accidentally disable user interaction forever.

Comment: I am getting this error Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

For above your requirement you must use ProgressDialog for same, here is an example

[Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progressbar.htm)

Comment: I have change my answer I did silly mistake apology for it. Check it now. It would help you.

Comment: That means do you want to create custom progress dialog?

Comment: Yes, I have solved this problem using progressDialog in previous version, but now in API level 26 it's deprecated, So i am trying to do it another way.

Comment: Okay cool, for same you can use Dialog, Using this you just need to create custom dialog, It's not deprecated. For your requirement it's more suitable than above example as my opinion.